# Detecting const-ness of nested type

Tags: c++, templates, constants, traits

Normally, if I need to detect whether a type is `const` I just use `boost::is_const`.  However, I ran into trouble when trying to detect the const-ness of a nested type.  Consider the following traits template, which is specialized for const types:

```
template <class T>
struct traits
{
    typedef T& reference;
};

template <class T>
struct traits<const T>
{
    typedef T const& reference;
};
```

The problem is that `boost::is_const` doesn't seem to detect that `traits<const T>::reference` is a `const` type.

For example:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << boost::is_const<traits<int>::reference>::value << " ";
std::cout << boost::is_const<traits<const int>::reference>::value << std::endl;
```

This outputs: `false false`

Why doesn't it output `false true`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the reference is not const, it's the type it's referencing that is const. Right, there are no const references. So imagine that the reference is a pointer, then the difference is easier to understand: `int const*` not const, `int *const` is const.

Use remove_reference to get the actual const type:

```
cout << boost::is_const<
            boost::remove_reference<int const&>::type>::value << '\n';
```

Answer (score 6):

Because references are not `const`. :)

You have a ref-to-const (consider a rough analog, `int const*`, where the pointee `int` has a `const` context, but the pointer itself does not). The standard mixes terminology here, but I avoid the term "const ref" which is highly misleading.

References are inherently immutable as they can only be initialised and then not re-bound, but that does not make them `const`.

You can remove the reference from the type with `boost::remove_reference` (as indicated in other answers).

Answer (score 4):

Well, have you noted that `is_const<int const&>::value` is likewise false?  It is.  Something like this should be among the first things you try in order to debug templates like this.  Another thing you can make use of is a type printer:

`template < typename T > struct print;`

When you instantiate that you'll get whatever T is in the error output, with most implementations.

Try this to solve your current problem:

`is_const< remove_reference< traits<int const>::reference >::type >::value`